# Notification doesn't show light with sound set

Tags: android, notifications

When I add .setDefaults(DEFAULT_SOUND) or DEFAULT_LIGHTS or DEFAULT_ALL, it shows the heads up notification, but doesnt show the light set with .setLights(0x0FF00FF0, 300, 100). If I remove the .setDefaults it doesn't show the heads up, but shows the lights.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.wgn.com"));
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
        .setContentTitle("Yi Warning")
        .setContentText("Battery is below 20%")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setVisibility(1)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
        .setLights(0x0FF00FF00, 300, 100).build();
NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed

```
.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
```

and added

```
.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
```

Now everything is working great :D